# Birthday Journey with no event entry source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio, birthday

I´m solutioning a Birthday journey and was wondering if this idea will work before running it by my client.

**Entry source:** *DE_[Tier]_BirthdayJourney*

- This DE is populated by an SQL query that runs every day at 6am. The logic is: 2 weeks before my birthday date, it updates the *BirthdayJourney* field [boolean format] to 1.

The journey runs after the above automation finish.

**Journey flow:**
Once in the journey, members will wait for 1 week and then receive the 1st email. After one week, based on their engagement (clicks) they will receive a reminder or not. After one week, the contact will be updated --> *BirthdayJourney* field [boolean format] to 0. Then, I will add 1 day wait before they exit the journey.

**Entry Criteria**

- Re-entry only after exiting.

**Exit Criteria**

- Opt-in is 0 (the member unsubscribes)

**My doubts are:**

- Will this set up ensure that members can re-enter every year without having to update neither the journey or the automation?
- Do you foresee any other issue that I should be aware of?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would highlight two points on your solution.

1. **Time Zones:** In which time zone is your birthday data coming in? And the time zone, in which the automation is running. Ideally, both should be same.
2. **Filter Criteria**: You should put a safety check as a filter criteria in your journey that only records where BirthdayJourney = 1, or use Antonio's method above, to ensure that not everyone is entering the journey.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You´re right time zones needs to be contemplated! Luckily this journey is for Europe and all the markets [therefore, member´s birthdays] share the same timezone. For the filter criteria, I do agree with you but as I explained to Antonio below, my client doesn´t have this fields related to Contact Data :(

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have the birthday date in Marketing Cloud somewhere? If so, I think you can simplify this by just having your SQL query look for everyone with a birthday +14 days from today and use the resulting data extension (configured as overwrite) as your journey entry source. As long as your journey settings allow re-entry, there should be no need to do anything else to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My client is not using SFDC, so all contact data comes through importations, and most of the member data is not connected to Contact Data through data relationships (fields such as tier, birthday, etc.). This is a big problem as our ideal scenario will be to add an exit criteria using Contact Data > Tier field so if the member changes tier [from Silver to Gold] it exits the journey. In fact, one of the dependencies in this journey will be that if the member changes tier during these two weeks, he will still receive messages corresponding to its previous tier.